# After EKS cluster is created by Terraform, next plan sees subnet changes to tags

Tags: terraform, amazon-eks

I am intending to use Terraform to stand up my entire monitoring infrastructure in AWS.
So far in my terraform project have created VPC, subnets, appropriate security groups. I am using the Terraform Registry where possible:

- [vpc](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws/1.41.0)
- [security-group](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/security-group/aws/2.5.0)
- [iam-role](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/anonymint/iam-role/aws/0.2.0)
- [eks](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/1.6.0)

The issue I am seeing is that after the EKS cluster is deployed it introduces tags to the VPC and Subnets that do not appear to be known to Terraform. Hence the next time `terraform plan` is run it identifying tags that it does not manage and intends to remove them:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------

An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  ~ update in-place

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  ~ module.vpc.aws_subnet.private[0]
      tags.%:                                "4" => "3"
      tags.kubernetes.io/cluster/monitoring: "shared" => ""

  ~ module.vpc.aws_subnet.private[1]
      tags.%:                                "4" => "3"
      tags.kubernetes.io/cluster/monitoring: "shared" => ""

  ~ module.vpc.aws_vpc.this
      tags.%:                                "4" => "3"
      tags.kubernetes.io/cluster/monitoring: "shared" => ""


Plan: 0 to add, 3 to change, 0 to destroy.

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

There is an issue open with [terraform-provider-aws](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws/issues/3143) with a [local workaround using bash](https://gist.github.com/gswallow/47a77aa153ff485dbd7f50eba667de15), but does anyone know how to get Terraform to become aware of these tags or to get them to be ignored by subsequent plans in a robust way?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Update*

Terraform now supports a provider wide [`ignore_tags` configuration block](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs#ignore_tags-configuration-block).

This means that one can set up a pattern of tags to ignore from the life cycle.

E.g.

```
provider "aws" {
  ignore_tags {
  key_prefixes = ["kubernetes.io"]
  }
}
```

and this will effectively act like a `lifecycle ignore` config for each resource managed.

*Original answer*

So in the end we chose not to use terraform to deploy the cluster at all,
instead we use `eksctl` the community based tool from Weaveworks.

https://eksctl.io/

It was recommended by an AWS solutions architect when we were at the AWS offices in London for some training.

The config can be stored in source control if needed.

```
eksctl create cluster -f cluster.yaml
```

Since EKS does a lot of tagging of infrastructure, our lives are much better now the state file is not complaining about tags.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the tags when you call the module, notice in the example of https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws/1.41.0 it shows tags there and in the docs it says "A map of tags to add to all resources" so you can add it to that map.

Comment: I thought of that, but I don't want to tag all the resources, for instance I'd only want to tag the subnets that EKS was activated in and not all of them. Having tags in *all* vpc resources would risk screwing up EKS's resource discovery mechanism. See  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/network_reqs.html#vpc-tagging

Comment: You should only tag the subnets according how EKS will tag them later.

Comment: @Spangen Thus said, add `kubernetes.io/cluster/monitoring: "shared"` to your tags in Terraform

Comment: And the tags will be applied to every resource that the VPC creates including all subnets. Suppose I had 2 private and 2 public subnets and the EKS cluster was only defined for the two private ones, what's to stop the public ones getting tagged by Terraform?

Comment: You would add the tags specifically in the VPC you are running EKS in, if you have subnets in your VPC that you do not want eks to use then you have to not tag those.

Answer (score -2):

If you controlled the module, you could try to use `ignore_changes` clause in the `lifecycle` block. Something like

```
    lifecycle {
      ignore_changes = [
        "tags"
    ]
}
```

It's going to be much trickier with a module that you don't control though.